# How to adjust cbar label position in sns.clustermap?

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

I'm ploting a seaborn clustermap and have problems to position the colorbar label. This is my code:

```
heatmap_plot = sns.clustermap(table, method=method, metric=metric, 
                                  row_colors=row_colors,
                                  col_cluster=col_cluster, row_cluster=row_cluster,
                                  cmap=color_scheme,
                                  xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True,
                                  # linewidths=1,
                                  cbar_kws={'label': cbar_label})

plt.setp(heatmap_plot.cax.yaxis.get_label(), rotation=270)
```

When I want to rotate cbar label text, it's overlapping with ticks and I have no idea how reposition it. Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem?

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You could leave out the colorbar label from the main `sns.clustermap` call and then do

```
heatmap_plot.cax.set_title("my cbar label")
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the solution... So far I set the coordinates manually and it also worked out  very well - `heatmap_plot.cax.yaxis.set_label_coords(cbar.x0 + cbar.width + 2.7 , hm.y0 + height/2)`

Comment: @Marija how do get access to cbar?